# X axis labels begin at the middle and do not match data points

Tags: r, axis

I either seem to be running in circles or there is something wrong with my data. I want to plot some data and use `?axis`to modify the labels on the X axis.

I have two issues however:

1. The axis labels begin in the center of the x-axis instead of at the beginning
2. The axis labels do not match the data points in the plot

I would like to have X axis labels ranging from 10 to 90 by 5.

This is the code that I use and came up with so far:

```
values <- cbind(1:180,1)

l <-    list(1:10,11:20,21:30,31:40,41:50,51:60,61:70,71:80,81:90,91:100,101:110,111:120,121:130,131:140,141:150,151:160,161:170,171:180)
# compute mean across the intervals in l
meanqual <- sapply(l, function(x) mean(values[x,1]))
meanqual
plot <- plot(meanqual, type="o", xlab="% Size of Wave", ylab="Values",xaxt='n', lty=1)
legend('bottomright', c("Values"),pch=21, lty=1, cex=1)
axis(side=1, at= seq(10,90,5))
```

[image: the plot that I get with x axis labels beginning in the center]

Comment: When you plot a vector, R assumes that the x values are simply integers 1 through the length of the vector, in this case 18 I think. So that's why R is placing the labels in the x axis the way it is.

Comment: You appear to want 17 axis tick labels. You'll have to decide where in the range 1-18 you want them to go, and then use both `at` and `labels` in `axis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only give one numeric vector to plot it "assumes" you meant to use the position or index of the values in that vector as the x values, so the plot call plotted `meanqual` against `1:length(meanqual)`. If you wanted to plot against the `seq()` argument you latter used in the axis call you should supply it (or rather something similar in scale with the same `length` as `meanqual`) to `plot`:

```
plot <- plot(x=seq(5,90,5), y=meanqual, type="o", 
             xlab="% Size of Wave", ylab="Values",xaxt='n', lty=1)
legend('bottomright', c("Values"),pch=21, lty=1, cex=1)
axis(side=1, at= seq(10,90,5), labels=seq(10,90,5))
```